# How to update Mac's system Python

Tags: macos, python, software-update

I'm on Mavericks at the moment, and i want to update the Python system's version (2.7.5) to the latest (2.7.7) from http://www.python.org, because i want to install pygame. 
What i have to do? I would like to be able to run the latest version of Python when i type `python` in the terminal, i searched for some guide on the net but it's all a bit confusing to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replacing Mac OS X's system Python is not recommended due to incompatability with other software. However, there are Mac binaries on the [Python download page](https://www.python.org/download/) that can be installed to a different location. Once installed, you may need to change your PATH environment variable so the new Python interpreter will run when `python` is invoked from the command line.

To edit your PATH, determine the absolute folder path containing the Python binary. This may look something like `/Applications/Python/.../bin`. Add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export PATH=/path/to/new/python/bin:$PATH
```

The change will take effect after you restart your shell.

Comment: Yeah i know that once installed the new Python folder is created in Applications, but how i update the PATH variable?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: `.bashrc` is not used on OS X. You need `.bash_profile`. Also don't forget to quote the `$PATH`, e.g. `export PATH="/path/to/bin/folder:$PATH"`

Comment: The new Python already done the update of the shell by himself! But now that i have installed pygame when i try to import it i receive

Comment: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper"

Comment: I have changed this but I still cannot get it to work. I didn't point to a /bin folder.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest, non-intrusive way would be to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then, read the instructions that are printed from your shell.

#### Installing Python 3

With Homebrew you can install Python 3.x:

```
brew install python
```

This will put a `python3` binary in `/usr/local/bin`, and a `python` binary pointing to `python3` in `/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin`.

You will additionally get a `pip3` command for that version of Python.

These formulas will not conflict or take precedence over the system packages unless you override your `PATH`. That is, if you want `python` to refer to `python3`, add the following to your shell config:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH
```

Read the [Homebrew Python docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html) for more info.

#### Installing Python 2.7

You can also get an up-to-date version of Python 2.7, if you require that for legacy reasons:

```
brew install python@2
```

This will give you a `python2` binary, and it will override the system `python` to use the Homebrew-built Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing [port](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html)?. I recently upgraded my python with port install on 10.8.4